# The callback function in celery

Tags: celery

Now I have two consumer:
task_A.py:

```
from B import task_b

@app_a.task
def task_a(args):
    # do something
    task_c.apply_async(args, link=task_a_a.s(args))

@app_a.task
def task_a_a()
    # do something
```

task_B.py:

```
@app_b.task
def task_b(*args)
    # do something
    return res
```

But I get error in task_B just like:

```
KeyError: 'task_A.task_a_a'
```

How to make it right

Answer (score 0):

Check `Task_c` is not present in function `task_a`.

```
task_c.apply_async(args, link=task_a_a.s(args))
```

It could be :

```
task_b.apply_async(args, link=task_a_a.s(args))
```